# Superscript before a letter using b quote

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript, letter

How can I add a superscript before to more than a  character (letter or a word) using bquote?

I used bquote as follow:

`bquote(X^2)`
and
 `bquote("Proteins "*log[2]~"FC")`